# Should there be tags for the language used in a question?

Tags: discussion

Should there be tags for the language used in a question?

Obviously, this would enable good filtering.

Upvote this question if you are in favour of:

Each question should have a tag lang:en or lang:de or lang:en-de

Comment: This suggestion might make language tagging superfluous: [Translating posts as a "community norm"](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/22)

Answer (score 7):

This would be a meta tag and meta tags are explicitly discouraged:

[**The Death of Meta Tags**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

The reason meta-tags are a problem is that they do not describe the content of the question. They describe how or why the question is being asked. You know a meta tag when you see it because meta tags don't make any sense unless they are paired with other tags. Inexperienced users often don't realize this and they start using those tags by themselves. It starts breaking the tagging system.

This isn't an obvious problem at first, but this was a *big* problem on other sites before we learned how to deal with them… by banning them outright.

Please don't repeat our mistakes of the past. No [english](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english) and no [german](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german) tags, please.

Answer (score 4):

I'm in favor of language tags for *minor* languages.

Spamming every question with [english](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english) or [german](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german) tags will be largely redundant, but if this site evolves to accept questions about many different languages in relation to German, language specific tags should be useful.

As a rule, I'd say that [german](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german) tags are useless, since every question should be about German on this site. [english](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english) is the lingua franca and would be equally redundant in most cases. Any other language used should be tagged.

See: [Wie kann man 気持ちいい am besten auf Deutsch ausdrücken?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/123/wie-kann-man-am-besten-auf-deutsch-ausdrucken) and [Should translation questions be bounded to German-English?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1406/should-translation-questions-be-bounded-to-german-english).